# Are they any way to improve JSP type safety?

Tags: java, validation, jsp, syntax, compilation

I added JSP compilation to my project, but still, compiler doesn't check wrong macros like ${object.value}, where object doesn't have getter for value.

I am wonder if there some other ways to guide JSP compiler (jspc) to do this. I was considering some options:
 1. Explicitly declare type of object inside JSP (jsp:useBean ?).
 2. Using <%= %> construction instead of ${ }

But nothing of this helped.

I would appreciate if anybody would share his experience in this area.

Answer (score 4):

Use `<jsp:useBean id="yourId" scope="request" type="com.blah.YourClass"/>` and precompile JSPs.

Read [this article](http://www.staldal.nu/tech/2009/04/23/type-safe-jsp-and-jstl/) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

No, unless you want to radically redesign how JSPs are done.

The HTML that it generates isn't type safe either.

The best you can do is to use Model-2 MVC, where you have servlets working alongside JSPs.  Let the servlet(s) worry about binding, validation, and making sure that the right objects end up in page scope.  Pages should be concerned only with display.

The scriptlet idea is a terrible one.  No one should be putting scriptlet code in a JSP.  Learn and use JSTL.